# Iterator becomes invalid after inserting in a boost::multi_index?

Tags: c++, boost-multi-index

According to the documentation, hashed index iterators remains valid when new elements are inserted into a multi_index. However when I attempted the following approach

```
auto& myIndex = myMultiIndex.get<0>();
auto range = myIndex.equal_range(x);
for (auto iter = range.first; iter != range.second; ++iter) {
    myMultiIndex.emplace(someArgsRelatedToIter);
}
```

the range.first/range.second seem to become invalid: even though std::distance(range.first, range.second) == 1, the for loop actually gets executed twice. Am I somehow not using it correctly? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that your end iterator is being updated when you add new things to `myMultiIndex`. It's not clear why you'd be adding arguments in a loop like this. Perhaps instead you can measure the `distance` and loop for that instead, so you get `auto size = std::distance(range.first, range.second);`, then `for (size_t index = 0; index < size; ++index)` and add your arguments that way? This is all just speculation which is why I haven't answered per se.

Comment: @Tas sorry for the confusion,I am actually trying to duplicate the elements in the range with some parameters updated (something like emplace(iter->oldParam, newParam)). Maybe there is a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

When c++ libraries specify that iterators aren't invalidated by an operation it means that the iterators still point to the same element. For example in the following code:

```
std::list< int > l;
l.push_back(1);
l.push_back(2);
l.push_back(3);
auto first = l.begin();
auto last = std::find(l.begin(), l.end(), 3);
std::cout << *first << std::endl;
std::cout << *last << std::endl;
```

`1`, `3` and `2` are printed. If we now insert some elements:

```
l.insert(last, 4);
l.insert(last, 5);
std::cout << *first << "\n";
std::cout << *last << "\n";
std::cout << std::distance(first, last) << "\n";
```

`first` and `last` are still valid and point to the same elements but the distance is now `4` so they point to a different range.